# Cordova super.loadUrl() blinks

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I'm using Cordova/PhoneGap 2.6.0. The main activity is as follows.

```
public class Main extends DroidGap
{
    private CordovaWebView cordova_webview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String url = "http://192.168.1.101/web/app.php/dashboard/";
        super.loadUrl(url);

    }
}
```

and the program blinks at the "super.loadUrl()" function.

I think that's natural, for the program initializes with the xml layout like `setContentView(R.layout.main);`
and the Cordova framework lies in the `super.loadUrl()`, so there must be a switch between the two views.

But is there a way to eliminate this "blink"?